# >У меня был только один вопрос: что он там такого сделал-таки?/

Tags: орфография

Мы при прямом вопросе, перед котором двоеточие, ставим обязательно вопросительный знак?

> У меня был только один вопрос: что он там такого сделал-таки?

> У меня был только один вопрос: что он там такого сделал-таки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При косвенном вопросе чаще не ставится, но может ставиться при вопросительной интонации. В прямом вопросе же знак обязателен:

*У меня был только один вопрос: что он там такого сделал-таки?*

[Здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%9F%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81) читайте про прямой вопрос.